# Making java Application in Net Beans for Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, netbeans, automated-tests

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //System.out.println("driver");
        String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
        //System.out.println(baseUrl);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

It throws me Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 0):

Need to download executable driver for Chrome. [Here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) download chrome driver and add code to initialize chrome driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path_to_driver/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

> WebDriver uses native browser approach. Selenium offers inbuilt driver for Firefox but not for other browsers. All drivers (Chrome Driver, IE driver, etc.) are built based on the special JS Engine used by each browser.

Basically Google Chrome doesn’t have a built-in server so you will need a Chrome driver server for communicating your Selenium code to the browser.

Instead `System.exit(0)` use `driver.quit()` method. It will close all opened browser window and terminates the WebDriver session. If you do not use driver.quit at the end of program, WebDriver session will not close properly and files would not be cleared off memory. This may result in memory leak errors.